# How do I know if a closed beta Game has Geographical IP Restrictions?

Tags: black-prophecy

I have been trying to get a hold for the Black Prophecy N.A Closed Beta.

Even though the name might be itself explicative, I have know various Closed North American Beta's that allowed people from regions outside N.A to play the Beta, for instance RIFT and World of Tanks just to name some.

I would like to know if it is ***possible***, if Black Prophecy N.A Closed Beta is geographically restricted to U.S, Canada and Mexico or if it allows regions such as South America for instance.

*LessPop MoreFizz* told me on chat that maybe due to a N.D.A even if someone knew they wont be allowed to tell, if this is the case, how would I be able to know, before I get the chance to try the key itself?

Comment: i would assume that this information would be available on the game site itself. However, any such geo-ip based system can be easily circumvented with proxies, although I am not sure if that is 'allowed'

Comment: Such detailed information was not specified on their site, and yes, in case they filter IP by geographical region, it could be bypassed by using proxies or VPN's but that would incur on additional costs for me

Comment: there are a lot of free proxies that are available for e.g. http://webevader.org/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible that Black Prophecy's closed beta is geographically restricted.  It's also possible that it's not, or that the restrictions don't catch for your location, or that circumventions allow you play the beta anyway.

The only way that you can find out whether it will work for you, and if can work around the restrictions, is to try it.